# Boundary Tracing

Tags: java, opencv

```
Mat img =Imgcodecs.imread(path);
Mat src = new Mat();

Imgproc.cvtColor(img, src, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(src, src, 127, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
Imgproc.Canny(src, src, 10,100, 3,true);


  ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
    Imgproc.findContours(src, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Mat contourImg = new Mat(img.size(), img.type());


    Point p= new Point(150,260);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(contourImg, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyStR.png)

How can I change the color of red ellipse when I clicked anyplace on ellipse area?
I can get x and y coordinates using mouse click but I can not operate "boundary tracing" .Here is the code that I wrote;

Answer (score 0):

If you have the contour coordinate of the boundary of the ellipse you can use the point in polygon test to check if the x,y of the mouse is inside the ellipse.

In opencv it is the function pointPolygonTest
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html